# Dell OpenManage On Ubuntu Server 12.04 Cannot Log In

Tags: ubuntu, dell, dell-poweredge, dell-openmanage

I have a Dell Poweredge 2950 with 2X130GB and 2X2TB drives. I need to set them up in a RAID 1 array so that the 130GB Drives are mirrored and host the OS, while the 2TB drives are mirrored and are the content drives. So I go from 4 disks, down to two, one 130GB and one 2TB. I can do that in the BIOS RAID utility no problem. But I need to be able to manage the RAID arrays and be able to expand them WITHOUT shutting down the server. Now, to my understanding, openmanage will allow me to do that AND it runs on ubuntu. So I go and set it up and try to log into the web interface at and it will not let me log in. I have followed dell's guide to set up openmanage, even added the usernames to the files and permissions and such, however, cannot get it to let me log in or anything. I have reinstalled Openmanage several times, even reinstalled the OS three times, and nothing works. Google does not help either. It simply says login failed after hitting submit. Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable the root account and set a password for it? IIRC you must use root for logging into the OMSA web GUI.